# record github repository collection by using git

Tags: git, github

I have several favorite github repository and I put them all in one folder A. The total size is 14mb. Then in the folder A. I want to record them also by using git. I use `git init.....` .But it seems git only add and commit empty folder since the `.git` folder is only 190k size. Why?

```
.
├── .git
├── FreeCodeCamp
├── Front-end-Developer-Interview-Questions
├── awesome
├── gitignore
└── the-art-of-command-line
```

Comment: Look into submodules: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Answer (score 1):

The filesize is small because the `git init` command is creating an empty repository for you. It does not add anything. To put your files into the repository, you should use `git add .` and `git commit`.

However, as Cad pointed out in his comment, if the folders you are trying to add are themselves git repositories, then you should use submodules to manage these. You can add new submodules `git submodule add <REPOSITORY URL>`. This will clone you a fresh copy of the repository and add all the necessary tracking information. At this point `git status` will reveal the changes that were made, and `git commit` will commit them.

Comment: In this way, do I need to delete these five original git repository folder?

Comment: Yes. I don't know any way around this. Make sure you push everything before deleting the folders, then the clone will be identical :)